Unable to Connect MySQL to Looker Studio - Error ID: ed911ec3
I'm trying to connect my MySQL database to Looker Studio but I'm encountering an error. When I attempt to establish the connection, I receive the following message:
"Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request. 
Error ID: ed911ec3"

Has anyone encountered this error before? What steps can I take to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Steps Taken:

Verified that my MySQL server is running and accessible.
Checked the credentials for correctness (username, password, database name).
Ensured that the MySQL user has the necessary permissions to access the database.
Confirmed that the IP address of Looker Studio is allowed through the MySQL firewall settings.
Tried connecting from a different network or device to rule out local issues.


is it your local mysql server?
